# Using water pressure as pushing force in a floating bath tub?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, water, buoyancy, fluid-statics

Does physics allow for water pressure to work in this way? if so What formula can prove this?

[image: gif]

<sup>([backup link 1](https://cs7065.vk.me/c404427/u140417658/docs/71efd5fdbeb2/Fizika.gif?extra=ZhluvWQ0EKVjoE1vNUdZzQvF4OrWzZcfEUO2QegytA1BdswOPWRrVlDZ7CmNcTrhZ4c2dCKtFDED-FdtdCgVwfLRb8g_iPQ), [backup link 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20160123165109/https://storage3.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0107/h_1452194220_6981893_7d32df0538.gif))</sup>

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We discourage link-only questions. And, I tried to edit that animated gif into your post, but it's over 5MB, and the limit is 2MB. Perhaps if you described what happened in the animation, or show a couple of stills from it, it would be clearer what your question is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The water will only come up to the water line along the outside of the floating bath tube, but it will effectively stop the leak if it fits.
[image]

Comment: But if the boat will become a submarine and it will sink at high speed the difference of the pressure can be used as a dynamical pressure i guess?

Comment: The air would equalize the water from coming in or if air pressure is low inside it will fill up with water till it does even out in pressure or have an air to water exchange and fill all the way. It can't ever work that way to push.

Comment: If the boat is pushing through the water, depending on the angle of the bow it might be possible to water to be pushed up and out. It would not be able to propel the boat though, since that would violate conservation of energy.